# Krillin in Dragon Ball Super

Tags: dragon-ball-super

How strong is Krillin in the latest episode against his fight with SSB Goku?
Is he as strong as Freiza in his 4th form?

He was able to hold SSB Kamehameha for a lot of seconds!
How is that even possible!

Comment: It's lame justification for him to be in the tournament, which they are positioning to be about strategy, not power level. Also, Goku can't kill him, so he can use any sort of Kamehameha he wants. Super Saiyajin Blue is a ki format. It need not have a fixed power level. It's the same as when Goku and Gohan exited the Room of Spirit and Time and remained SSJ for 9(?) days.

Comment: I haven't watched the universal tournament saga yet, but as @VISQL stated above SSB is a transformation that doesn't just raise the level, it changes the ki from conventional ki to god ki which can do anything you want with. 

The main difference is ki control, remember SSB is a super saiyan with god ki. Meaning god control.

Comment: In the Fukkatsu no F movie Goku is almost killed with a laser weapon when in Super Saiyan Blue. So I guess in Super Saiyan Blue you can lower your ki even close to human levels